# How to initially collapse All rows in a nested table using only Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

[In this plunker demo,](http://plnkr.co/edit/kICmEPNe8Qnp6Fherr5W?p=preview) I'm getting by default *rows expanded*. But I need it initially collapsed and also, **when I expand any one row, all others should be collapsed**. All these functions I need using only JQuery...Can anyone help me out?..thanks in Advance

**JQuery**

```
    <script>
  $(function ()  {
    $('#mytable').on('click', '.toggle', function () {

        var findChildren = function (tr) {
            var depth = tr.data('depth');
            return tr.nextUntil($('tr').filter(function () {
                return $(this).data('depth') <= depth;
            }));
        };

        var el = $(this);
        var tr = el.closest('tr'); 
        var children = findChildren(tr);

        var subnodes = children.filter('.expand');
        subnodes.each(function () {
            var subnode = $(this);
            var subnodeChildren = findChildren(subnode);
            children = children.not(subnodeChildren);
        });

        if (tr.hasClass('expand')) {

            tr.removeClass('expand').addClass('collapse');
            children.show();

        } else {
            tr.removeClass('collapse').addClass('expand');
            children.hide();
        }
        return children;
    });

});
</script>
```